# Difference between failed task and killed task attempt?

Tags: mapreduce

Does failed task attempt thrown an unhandled exception ?
Who will terminate killed task attempt ?
Does a killed task attempt thorws any exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop will, for example, start a map task again if it has the resources for that and if a currently running map task is doing very slow-> if there is a chance that a running map task fails it tries to start a second instance of the task (Speculative Execution). This leaves you with two options about the outcome of the job. Either the map task, which was started earlier will eventually finish and hadoop will kill the second map task(this will leave u with one killed task), since it is not needed anymore or the first task will fail and then (hopefully) the second one will succeed (this leaves you with one failed task). At least this is what I understood from google-ing around. Here is a link to this explanation from the book:
[Hadoop:Speculative Execution](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/task-execution)

Hope I helped!

Cheers